# Silverlight App on Surface 2.0

Tags: silverlight, pixelsense

I can't find an answer to this question :
Can we run a Silverlight App on the Microsoft Surface 2.0 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [development whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=26715), yes -- sort of.  If you're running in Windows Mode, you're just running straight up Windows 7 and should be able to run your Silverlight application.  However, you won't have access to any of the Surface APIs.  If you're running in Surface Mode, all of the Surface APIs are for WPF according to the block diagram in the white paper.